# Django Method Not Allowed (POST): password_reset/done

Tags: django, post, passwords, reset

I'm new on Django / Python.

I'm trying to implement a mechanism to reset user's password via e-mail. In order to do that I'm trying to use as much as possible the Django native library django.contrib.auth

Although, when processing my custom made password_reset_form.html (see below) I got an error:

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /accounts/password_reset/done/

```
<form method="post" class="m-t" role="form" action="{% url 'password_reset_done' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="id_forgot_email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required="">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Reset password</button>
</form>
```

Anyone has clue why post method is not permitted? I've checked the following [Django Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication) that uses a post method in exactly the same file...

Answer (score 5):

You are posting to the wrong URL. `password_reset_done` is the view used to confirm that the password has been reset - the user is redirected to that view after a successful reset.

The tutorial has `action=""` on the form - which is different from what you have in yours. You need to change your form to use `action=""` (which is the current URL). Or if for some reason you want to be more explicit, then:

```
action="{% url 'password_reset' %}"
```